# nginx crawlable site facebook share

Tags: ajax, facebook, nginx, web-crawler, share

My site is following the ajax crawlable specifications, and it's already been indexing pages perfectly.

Currently I am trying to integrate social sharing via facebook, twitter, etc.
This in not working....

My setup is quite simple:
- grunt task to create static snapshots
- nginx rewrite rule to point to snapshots when _escaped_fragment_ param is used.

The issue here is facebook escapes the characters, e.g. for URL mawla.io/#!/blog facebook will substitute like this mawla.io/?_escaped_fragment_=%23blog, which will look up the snapshot like this:

path/to/snapshots%23blog.html

Which will obviously result in a 404...
Is there a way to unescape %23 to / in nginx??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax Crawlable spec seems to hint that unencoding is done on the the implementers side, so it means either using NGINX with the lua plugin and unescapedEncoding or perhaps run incoming traffic to certain base URLs through a service.

We actually just created escaped_fragments for the encoded values as a lazy hack around this.